# Is *a* optional after *both*?

Tags: grammar, articles

This is a quote from a book:

> Leibniz was *both* philosopher and mathematician.

To me it should be "both *a* philosopher and (*a*) mathematician." Is the article **a** optionall after **both**? Does **both** includes **a**?

Comment: Searched on authentic sites, both practices are okay - with or without articles. But it's a thought provoking question. +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If he is just one of them:

> Leibniz was **a** philosopher.

then *a* is necessary. But when he is both:

> Leibniz was **both** philosopher and mathematician.

then he is two things (philosopher and mathematician), so *a* is not appropriate.
However, as you mentioned you could say;

> Leibniz was both **a** philosopher and **a** mathematician.

which treats each one separately. I believe this would be technically correct.

Comment: Can I leave out *both*? Is it grammatically correct: "He was philosopher and mathematician"?

Comment: Then I think you need both "a"s in there. "He was a philosopher and a mathematician".

Answer (score 2):

That sentence is grammatically correct, although it would be a bit clearer if the **a** were included.  **Both** can include **a**, although it is more common to see them used together, as it typically clarifies the sentence.

A more common usage of **both** by itself might be, for example, in a eulogy.  Something like "I knew him as both Grandfather and friend."  In this case, the addition of an article would not serve to clarify the sentence or make it more readable.